# Cannot return null for non-nullable field Tag.links

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

I have data model like below

```
type Tag {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  icon: String
  description: String!
  links: [Link!]!
}

type Link {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  description: String!
  url: String!
  tags: [Tag!]!
}
```

I want to query all the tags based on names and i am able to do that by the below query

```
   tags (name:"tag1"){
    id
    name
  }
```

**this query works**
but for the same query i want to return all the links associated with the tag name like below

```
tags(name:"tag1") {
    id
    name
    links {
      id
      description
    }
  }
```

i am getting following error when executing this

```
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Tag.links.",
```

**Resolver for this query**

```
const tags = await context.prisma
        .tags({name: args.name
        })
```

Comment: Please include the relevant resolver code

Comment: @DanielRearden updated